How to join the rows of unrelated tables in SQL into one view?
I'm working on a way to create an index table without having some sort of cron run to update it on a schedule. I thought I could use a view to search through might be the best option.
I have up to 5 tables I want to join that are completely unrelated. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:
Table One (Pages):



id
name
slug




1
Resources
resources


2
Contact Us
contact-us



Table Two (Blogs):



id
title
desc




4
How to Use the Web
basic description


7
Hello World!
hello hello!



Desired View Result:



id
name
searchparam




1
Resources
resources


2
Contact Us
contact-us


4
How to Use the Web
basic description


7
Hello World!
hello hello!



I'm looking to keep the rows intact but rename them to the final view result. If needed, I'm also be adding additional searchparam columns like searchparam2, searchparam3... etc if I need more  information. What would be the best way to join multiple tables into a view I can lookup later?
Thank you!

You know about UNION? See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/union.html

You can use a Common Table Expression (aka. CTE) to merge tables with different column names into desired structure. Here's the solution:
WITH searchable AS (
    SELECT 
        p.id::text,
        p.name AS name,
        p.slug AS searchparam
    FROM pages p 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        b.id::text,
        b.title as name,
        b.desc as searchparam,
    FROM blogs b
    /* UNION ALL
    SELECT ... continue the pattern as many table as you want
    */
    
)
SELECT * FROM searchable;


Here's an example output


This is an example query and please consider optimizing data types and create proper index to get faster results if you're planning to have search feature in production.
